# How to modify data table column values in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

In Elastic search we store events, I have built data table which aggregates based on event types. I have filter which checks for event.keyword : "job-completed". I am getting the count as 1 or 0 but i want to display as completed / in-progress.

How to achieve this in Kibana ?

Answer (score 1):

The best and more effective way to do this is to add another field with and to complete it at the ingest time.
It the best solution regarding on performance. But it can lead to an heavy work.

You can also use a scripted field to do this without touching your data.
Do to stack management > kibana > index pattern and select your index.
Select scripted field tab and fill in form.
Name : your_field
language: painless
type: string
format: string
script:

```
if(doc['event.keyword'].value=='job-completed'){
    return "completed";
 }else {
         return "in progress";
}
```

I got to few information on your real data to be able to give you a working code, so you'll have to modify it to fit your needs.

Then refresh you visualization and you can use your new field